# How to redirect everything to a directory?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am organizing my public_html directory. I copied all scattered files and directories from root public_html into public_html/main directory. I would like to redirect all requests into "main" directory, basically just adding "main/" to the URL. For example:

**...mydomain.com** goes to **...mydomain.com/main**

**...mydomain.com/product_page.php** goes to **...mydomain.com/main/product_page.php**

*notes: Just replace the ... above with "www." because I am not allowed to post links.

I tried this rule below in .htaccess but doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^main/?$    http://www.mydomain.com/main/    [R=301,NC,L]
```

Is there something wrong with that?

Thanks.

hc.

Comment: RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /main$1

Answer (score 0):

RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) /main$1

Comment: Hi, I got this ...mydomain.com/mainmainmainmainmainmainmainmainmain/